# Maximize ELBO in Keras

Tags: keras

When we train a Variational Autoencoder we say that we want to maximize the ELBO. However, from the Keras documentation, it seems that we are actually minimizing the ELBO

```py
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
   xent_loss = objectives.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
   kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_sigma - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_sigma), axis=-1)
   return xent_loss + kl_loss
```

The above function should return the positive ELBO from my understanding. Shouldn't we return the negative ELBO since Keras always minimize the loss function?